# Distorted content when scaling UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, scaling

I have a UIImageView with a frame of (0, 0, 568, 300) containing a UIImage with a native size of 512x384 pixels. The contentmode is set to Aspect fit.
If the user double-Taps on the view I change the size of the UIImageView with the following code:

```
self.imageViewerViewController.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -63, 568, 426);
```

the result is that the right edge of the image is distorted, it does not properly scale to the new size.

Attached is an image with a black and white matrix, the distortion is on the right.
It seems that the right column of pixels is repeated to the right edge of the view.

[image: screenshot of the distortion]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the creation of the affected UIImageView from a xib file to creating it in code  and using the method `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect:` with the maximum size of the scaled image for aRect. Now the image is properly scaled.
Obviously the UIImageView in the xib file has been inited with a 512x384 pixel frame.